# LNK2019 Error: Project converterd in Visual Studio 2010 but can not compile it

Tags: visual-c++, lnk2019

I need to compile a project which is automatically created from a simulation programm. I tried to compile it with Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 2010. After converting the project i  have the following error LNK2019:

> 1>libcarmaker.a(DataDict.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___fpclassifyf referenced in function *DDictStr2Place
>
>   1>libcarmaker.a(DataDict.o) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*_fpclassify referenced in function _DDictStr2Place
>   1>CarMaker.win32.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========,

There are a lot of threads relating to this error but none of those solutions worked for me.

Could anyone help me how to solve it??

Comment: You have to actually **read** the other posts, all of which eventually end up being answered by "add the libraries or object files that provide those symbols to your project". So add the object or library file that contains the definition of `fpclassifyf`. I don't know where your simulation program thinks it's coming from, so I can't tell you which specific library to add.

Answer (score 1):

`fpclassify` is supported [only in Visual Studio 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh308268.aspx). In VS 2010 it is [`_fpclass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/39s1cck2%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), so you should rename where the function is called.

[Source](http://www.johndcook.com/math_h.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answers.. The simulation program is "IPG CarMaker" and has special libs. One of them is the "libcarmaker.a", which causes error while compiling. I opened it with text editor but the half of datei is unreadable. I found though ___fpclassifyf and ___fpclassify in libcarmaker.a and renamed it. Then tried to build project again but i got a new error which is "fatal error LNK1127: library is corrupt". What am i doing false?

Comment: It's much better to ask a new question with details, I think it's a completely different problem